# Windows has triggered a breakpoint in c?

Tags: c++, c

A dialog appears when execution in run time reaches at the statement free(dat)

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in project.exe. This may be due to
>   a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in project.exe or any
>   of the DLLs it has loaded.

```
while(1)
{
    char *dat;

    std::cout<<"Enter command\n";
    memset(command, 0, 30);
    std::cin>>command;
    m_size = strlen(command)+2;
    printf("send data Size: %d\n",m_size);
    command[m_size-2] = '\r';
    dat = (char*)malloc(m_size);
    if(!dat)
    {
        printf("mem allocation failed");
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(dat,command,sizeof(command));
        ok = send_data(dat);
    }
    if(ok>0)
    {
    printf("send data: %s\n",dat);

    }
    free(dat);
}
```

// Orignal code look like this

```
int main()
{
    char command[30];
    While(1)
    {....}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is `command` declared?

Comment: If this is supposed to be C++, use `std::string` and *don't* use `malloc` except for C interop. Plus, lose the C tag.

Comment: if you do not show how command is declared you leave us with guesses at best.

Comment: int main()
{char command[30];While(1){....}}

Comment: You're allocating `m_size` bytes and copying `sizeof(command)` bytes. Something looks fishy here.

Comment: Do you get the crash if `ok = send_data(dat)` is commented?

Comment: @Bathsheba still same

Comment: @Bathsheba later i need to add '\r' later on thats y allocated +2

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't even get what he is asking about?

Comment: You shuld terminate command with `'\0'` after putting the `'\r'` and use `strdup` like this  `dat = strdup(command)` instead of the `malloc` and `memcpy`. don't forget to `free`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution1**
Replace `memcpy(dat,command,sizeof(command));` with `memcpy(dat,command,m_size);`

(Don't overwrite the buffer allocated)

**Solution2**
Or use `dat =(char *)malloc(sizeof(command));`

(Allocate bigger buffer if you want to write more)

**Solution3**
After `command[m_size-2] = '\r';`, add another line

```
command[m_size-1] = '\0'; /* Make it NUL terminated */
```

And replace `memcpy(dat,command,sizeof(command));` with `strcpy(dat, command)`

(Use strcpy instead of memcpy)

**Solution4**

```
while(1)
{
    std::string command;
    std::cout<<"Enter command\n";
    std::cin>>command;
    command += '\r';
    ok = send_data(command.c_str());
    if(ok>0)
    {
        printf("send data: %s\n",dat.c_str());
    }
}
```

Write C++ style code (`std::string` as your compiler is C++)

Comment: you have to cast the return value of malloc in c++

Answer (score 4):

The amount of memory you allocate for `dat` is `m_size`

```
dat = (char*)malloc(m_size);
```

The amount of memory you modify through `dat` is `sizeof(command)`

```
memcpy(dat,command,sizeof(command));
```

Why?

Judging by the rest of the code, `sizeof(command)` is generally greater than `m_size`, which means that by that `memcpy` you overwrite your memory and destroy the integrity of the heap. Hence the crash on `free(dat)`.